# Android:Espresso: Can't check is success start activity

Tags: android, android-espresso

Android Studio 3.2

I have 2 activities.
One activity (`TradersActivity`)  has list. Every item hast button "**Json View**". when click this button (on item with position **15**) then open another activity `JsonViewActivity`. I want to create Espresso's test that check that when I click this button then success open new activity `JsonViewActivity`

Here Espresso's test:

```
import org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.not
import java.util.*
import org.junit.Rule
import org.junit.Test
import org.junit.runner.RunWith
import androidx.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.isDisplayed
import android.graphics.Typeface
import android.view.View
import androidx.test.espresso.action.ViewActions.swipeLeft
import androidx.test.espresso.intent.Intents.intended
import androidx.test.espresso.intent.matcher.IntentMatchers.hasComponent
import androidx.test.rule.ActivityTestRule

@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class TradersActivityTest {
    @Rule
    @JvmField
    var tradersActivitytRule = ActivityTestRule(TradersActivity::class.java)

    @Test
    fun itemList_viewJsonButton_click_check() {
        //scroll
        onView(withId(R.id.tradersRecyclerView))
                .perform(RecyclerViewActions.scrollToPosition<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>(15));
        // click
        onView(withRecyclerView(R.id.tradersRecyclerView).atPositionOnView(15, R.id.viewJsonButton))
                .perform(click())
        // chekk ist start JsonViewActivity activity
        intended(hasComponent(JsonViewActivity::class.java.getName()))
    }
```

But I get error:

```
$ adb shell am instrument -w -r   -e debug false -e class 'com.myproject.android.activity.TradersActivityTest#itemList_viewJsonButton_click_check' com.myproject.android.debug.test/androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner
Client not ready yet..
Started running tests

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.test.espresso.intent.Intents.internalIntended(org.hamcrest.Matcher, androidx.test.espresso.intent.VerificationMode, java.util.List)' on a null object reference
at androidx.test.espresso.intent.Intents$2.check(Intents.java:194)
at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$SingleExecutionViewAssertion.check(ViewInteraction.java:419)
at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$2.call(ViewInteraction.java:282)
at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$2.call(ViewInteraction.java:268)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)

Tests ran to completion.
```

Answer (score 0):

It works if you use `IntentsTestRule` instead `ActivityTestRule`.